# scala TreeMap - how to get indexOf and element to use with slice or view method

Tags: scala

I am trying to find a datastructure that can do a constant lookup and then scan next sorted element from that point until end element is reached. Basically linear scan on sorted set but instead of doing it from first element it should start from specific element so i can scan a range effectively. TreeMap might be a right datastructure for it. Correct me if I'm wrong there. I am trying to use its `def
slice(from: Int, until: Int): TreeMap[A, B]` and supply `from` and `to` values as indexOf element to start and end scan. I can't find a method to get indexOf treeMap element based on Key. I'm sure its internally there but is it expose somewhere? Also, what's the performance of this method? Is it really better then doing linear scan from first element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you are looking for [TreeMap.from()](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap@from(from:A):scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap[A,B]) or [TreeMap.iteratorFrom()](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap@iteratorFrom(start:A):Iterator[(A,B)]) or [TreeMap.range()](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap@range(from:A,until:A):scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap[A,B])